# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model_12" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), found shape=(256, 256, 3)

Tags: neural-network, keras, tensorflow, convolutional-neural-network, error-handling

I am following [this](https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_from_scratch/) keras example with my own dataset, which has 3 classes. I load the images using

`train = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(cloud_dir, labels = "inferred", label_mode="categorical", batch_size=None)`

I am not using a validation set nor a batch size. I am also augmenting and prefetching the data set by

```
data_augmentation = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.layers.RandomFlip("horizontal"),
        keras.layers.RandomRotation(0.1),
    ]

train = train.map(
    lambda img, label: (data_augmentation(img), label),
    num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE,
)

train = train.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

The `train` object is now of the following type

`<ParallelMapDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(256, 256, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(3,), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))>`

I wanted to play around with layers since I am new to neural networks and my dataset is not the same as in the example, so my model is not exactly like the one given in the link.

```
def make_model(input_shape, num_classes):
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=input_shape, batch_size=None)
    x = layers.Rescaling(1.0 / 255)(inputs)
    for size in [32,64,128]:
        x = layers.Conv2D(size, (2,2), strides=2, padding="same", input_shape = input_shape)(x) 
        x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)
        x = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same')(x)

    activation = "softmax"
    units = num_classes
    outputs = layers.Dense(units, activation=activation)(x)
    return keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

model = make_model(input_shape=(256,256,3), num_classes=3)
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True)
```

Finally I compile and train the model

```
epochs = 25

callbacks = [
    keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("save_at_{epoch}.keras"),
]
model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-3),
    loss="binary_crossentropy",
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)

model.fit(
    train,
    epochs=epochs,
    callbacks=callbacks
)
```

However, at this point I get the error from the title

`ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model_12" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), found shape=(256, 256, 3)`

I don't know why the layers expect the extra `None` dimension and I don't know how to reshape the train object. I have tried reshaping using the answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60486437/add-none-dimension-in-tensorflow-2-0) but the type of my train object is not subcriptable.

> Can someone explain me why and how I should make shapes match?

Comment: Model needs a batch dimension, therefore you need to set your batch size. That's how Keras works.

Comment: @Frightera thank you! I also needed to add a global average pooling layer to so that the output would match the dimension of the labels.